# Where do I go to ask this question

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Need recommendation for VPN router features](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38036/need-recommendation-for-vpn-router-features)

I was mainly asking for protocol recommendations.  Please direct to me the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment to your question, you could try to ask the question on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

As far as I know, [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) are the only SE sites that permit product recommendations.

For something like you want, I would strongly urge you to hire someone for a couple of hours to set this up for you. Since you don't know how to get a cert, This is probably something you should have a professional do. Doing it incorrectly will leave you wide open, even if it looks secure to you.

Comment: I guess my question was unclear. My main goal was not to get product recommendations but rather to get advice on industry standard protocols. As for hiring someone, we did that. We're in a small rural community not blessed with great IT resources. The Cisco RV180 was the recommendation of our hired gun.

Comment: The industry standard protocol _is_ IPsec. If you need a cert, then you buy one from a cert vendor (Certificate Authority).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I'll do some IPSec research now.